# How should I conventionally name a linux-based C++ library?

Tags: c++

When installing libraries for C++ on Ubuntu 15.10 via the terminal, I notice that a lot of them are named along the lines of `libexample-dev` or maybe `libexample2`. When naming libraries for Linux programming, how should I go about doing so conventionally? Also what is meant by `dev` at the end and what are the other things that could follow the dash after the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library is not the same as the Debian/Ubuntu package providing it.

The `libfoo-dev`  (so called development) package often provides some header files and the static library (needed to *build* source programs using that library).

The `libfoo` package is providing the shared libraries (needed by other programs and packages to run).

Often the `libfoo-dev` package is depending upon its `libfoo` package.